# How to check if voucher is expired after it purchased one year.?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I am building a voucher generate system in laravel. This voucher validity period is one year. Now i want do is when user trying to redeem a voucher then user cannot do it because of it is expired. Any one can help me to do this. Because I don't have any idea about this.

This is what I am tried

```
$voucher = Voucher::where('code', $request->code)->first();

        $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $startdate = $voucher['created_at'];
        $offset = strtotime("+365 day");
        $enddate = date($startdate, $offset);
        $today_date = new  \DateTime($today);
        $expiry_date = new \DateTime($enddate);

        if ($expiry_date < $today_date) {

            return response()->json(['error' =>"Voucher is expired"]);
        }
```

Comment: show your code. What you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're storing the vouchers in the database, you can add a `valid_until` date column and verify that it's in the past before redeeming the voucher.

Comment: No I want to track it with created_at date. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Basing the expiry date off the `created_at` field could be problematic in the future if the expiry rules change. For example consider what would happen if after a while you decide that vouchers should actually expire after 6 months. If I had purchased a voucher which was expected to last a year then it wouldn't be fair that mine expires early.
A better approach as mentioned in a previous answer would be to store the expiry date in a separate column in the table. This would make the code that checks for expiry much simpler and also would allow you to have different expiry times if required, e.g. a premium voucher could last for 2 years instead of just one.